# Hibernate in JavaFX - displaying records from selected ID

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to display all records from selected ID on ListView, but how can I display for example record from selected ID from column 'name' in Hibernate? In MySQL it looks like that and it works fine:

```
@Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String idvalue) {
            try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM przychodniadb.patient WHERE idpatient=" + idvalue);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    infoPIDField.setText(rs.getString(1));
                    infonameField.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    infolastNameField.setText(rs.getString(3));
                    infogenderField.setText(rs.getString(4));
                    infoageField.setText(rs.getString(5));
                    infophonenumberField.setText(rs.getString(6));
                    infoadressField.setText(rs.getString(7));
                    infodiseaseField.setText(rs.getString(8));
                    infoconditionField.setText(rs.getString(9));
                    infodataField.setText(rs.getString(12));
                    infoRoomNumber.setText(rs.getString(13));
                    infoRoomType.setText(rs.getString(10));*/

                }

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Now in Hibernate:

```
@Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String>  observable, String oldValue, String idvalue) {

Query query3 = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Patient WHERE idpatient=:idpatient");
                query3.setParameter("idpatient", idvalue);


                    infoPIDField.setText(???);
                    infonameField.setText(???);
                    infolastNameField.setText(???);
                    ...........


    });
```

What should I put as parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First take the result in `Patient` object like this:

`Patient c = (Patient) query.getSingleResult();`

Thereafter you can access those fields using simple getters.

```
@Override
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String>  observable, String oldValue, String idvalue) {

    Query query3 = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Patient WHERE idpatient=:idpatient");
    query3.setParameter("idpatient", idvalue);

    Patient p = (Patient) query.getSingleResult();


    infoPIDField.setText(p.getPIDField());
    infonameField.setText(p.getNameField());
    infolastNameField.setText(p.getLastNameField());
    ...........


}
```